# Getting an Instance of IModuleManager in the Shell

Tags: wpf, prism, mef

I've been trying to write a WPF application using PRISM and MEF and I've been able to get the Shell up and running. I want to be able to load Modules on demand so I need an instance of IModuleManager in the Shell. However, when I try to import it, the application breaks. Here is the relevant code:

Bootstrapper:

```
public class Bootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return this.Container.GetExportedValue<Shell>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();

        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Shell)this.Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {
        base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();

        // Add this assembly to export ModuleTracker
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Bootstrapper).Assembly));

        DirectoryModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = new DirectoryModuleCatalog();
        moduleCatalog.ModulePath = @".\Modules";
        moduleCatalog.Load();
        foreach (ModuleInfo moduleInfo in moduleCatalog.Modules)
        {
            this.ModuleCatalog.AddModule(moduleInfo);
        }

        DirectoryCatalog catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@".\Modules");
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(catalog);

        base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        //Export the Container so that it can be injected if needed.
        this.Container.ComposeExportedValue(Container);

        //Export the Module Catalog so that it can be injected if needed.
        this.Container.ComposeExportedValue(ModuleCatalog);

        base.ConfigureContainer();
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        return new ConfigurationModuleCatalog();
    }
}
```

Shell:

```
[Export(typeof(Shell))]
public partial class Shell : Window, IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
{
    [Import(AllowRecomposition = false)]
    private IModuleManager moduleManager;

    public Shell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void OnImportsSatisfied()
    {

    }
}
```

The exception I'm getting is:

```
No exports were found that match the constraint: 
ContractName    Shell
RequiredTypeIdentity    Shell
```

If I remove the [Import] attribute for the IModuleManager, everything works fine. Is there something I need to do to export IModuleManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue by commenting the following line in the Bootstrapper:

```
this.Container.ComposeExportedValue(ModuleCatalog);
```

Not sure why it was causing an issue but would welcome any insights into this matter.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you have to watch out for is having multiple exports for the same type. This can easily happen when you are using `ComposeExportedValue` as well as using a `DirectoryCatalog` (which could contain an `Export` of the same type).

There is a great package on Nuget for diagnosing these problems called [MEFX](http://nuget.org/packages/MEFX.Core.Unofficial/)

If you get this library, you can add the following lines to help find out what is going on

```
var compositionInfo = new CompositionInfo(AggregateCatalog, Container);
CompositionInfoTextFormatter.Write(compositionInfo, Console.Out);
```

I would be interested to see what this prints to the Output window when you leave `this.Container.ComposeExportedValue(ModuleCatalog);` in your program, if you wouldn't mind posting any errors from it.